# android -Fragments - onConfigurationChanged -it's possible to change only the layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation, onconfigurationchanged

I have a question related to fragments, the only solution to change the fragment layout it's if I remove the old instance and replace with new one? 
I have two layout's one for portrait and one for landscape - I want to keep all the information's(data) and only replace the layout the  onConfigurationChanged() method is called, but I can't force the fragment to recreate the layout.

Thanks, Lorand

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can only change your layout without reloading your data.
My solution is 
Don't put  android:configuration='orientation' 
in the manifest.xml.

When rotating screen, normally onCreateActivity will be call and it'll take the good layout AND RELOAD your data.